# How does #including standard library work?

Tags: c, io, linker, include, c-preprocessor

My basic question is how the compilation process works to use standard library routines. When I  `#include <stdio.h>` in **C**, does the preprocessor take the entire standard library and paste it into my source file?

If this is so, when I use a library routine, how is it that the linker is involved?

Comment: To give you a hint, the only way to not include a linker at all is to turn the compiled program into a complete operating system. Remember that some function calls are calls to functions provided by the operating system; i.e. opening and reading from a file. The standard library does not include all the code necessary for this to happen; it delegates the actual work to the OS.

Comment: As an exercise, just create a .c file that **only** contains `#include <stdio.h>` , compile it (eg with `gcc -c file.c`, and look at the generated object (maybe with objdump).

Answer (score 4):

The preprocessor is, as its name implies, a program that runs before the compiler. All it does is simple text substitutions.

When a `#include` directive is found, it simply "pastes" the complete file into the place where the directive was. The same applies to macro expansions, when a macro "call" is detected, the body of the macro is "pasted" into its place.

The preprocessor has nothing to do with libraries. It's just that C (and C++) needs to have all its functions and variables declared before they are used, and so putting the declarations in a header file that is included by the preprocessor is a simple way to get these declarations from libraries.

There are basically two types of libraries: Header only libraries, and libraries you need to link with. The first type, header only libraries, are exactly what the name implies: They are fully contained in the header files you include. However, the vast majority of libraries are libraries you need to link with. This is done in a step *after* the compiler has done its work, by a special program. How this is used depends on the environment of course.

In general, compilation of a program can be divided into these steps:

1. Editing
2. Preprocessor
3. Compiler
4. Linker

The editing step is what you do to create your source.

The preprocessor and compilation steps are often put together into a single step, which is probably why there is some confusion among beginners as to what the preprocessor really does.

The final step, linking, is taking the input from the compiler, and uses that together with the libraries you specified to create the final executable.

Answer (score 2):

> When I pound include in C, does the preprocessor take the entire standard library and paste it into my source file?

Only the header files you `#include`.

> If this is so, when I use a library routine, how is it that the linker is involved?

The standard library headers contain **declarations only.** The **definition** (implementation) of the functions is in a library file, most likely `/usr/lib/libc.ext` (`ext` being an OS-dependent extension).

Answer (score 1):

When you #include something in your source code, the preprocessor pastes whatever you #include into your source file.
But specifically, if you include a header file from a library, you are just including function declarations like `void a();`, and the linker finds implementations of these functions in the library itself.

Comment: I hope you are not trying to get to the top with your answer by downvoting mine...!?

Comment: Suspicious timing, and the fact that your answer basically says the same as his and didn't get voted down.  I was wondering about it too, actually.

Comment: sorry, I didn't mean it like that, I was just fed up with several other questions at the moment too..